# Heroku + Rails Workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed my app on Heroku but am running into issues that I don't have when running the app locally.  Because of this, I'm making a lot of tweaks to my code, and I'm finding that my workflow for pushing new code to Heroku takes a long amount of time (about 5 min each time), so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.  Before I push my code, I precompile my assets using

```
rake assets:precompile
```

This takes a few minutes to do.  Then I do a commit and push my code to Heroku using:

```
git push heroku master
```

This also takes a few minutes to do.  Do I need to precompile every time I push code to Heroku?  Is there any way of making this process faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - The Heroku Ruby buildpack will run assets:precompile for you if you haven't already.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: thanks for your response.  so this means that heroku will precompile my assets automatically every time I push to it?